# How to show that $P(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{2^n\cdot x^n}{(n+1)\cdot(n+2)}}$ converges, $ \ \forall z \in \mathbb{C}:|z| = \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

The ratio test was used  to prove that $P(x)$ converges for $|z| < \frac{1}{2}$. Now I have to show that $P(x)$ also converges at $|z| = \frac{1}{2}$. I don't know how to proceed as there are infinite points (a circle in the complex plane) with a distance of $\frac{1}{2}$ away from any point.

Comment: Use the telescopic sum.

Comment: It's enough to prove that the sum of the absolute values, i.e., $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$ converges, which it does by comparison to $p$-series, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just  show it converges absolutely: $$\begin{align*}\sum_{n\geqslant 0} \left|\frac{2^n z^n}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right| &= \sum_{n \geqslant 0} \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} \\ & = \sum_{n \geqslant 0 }\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right) \\ & = 1\end{align*}$$ by telescoping (the tail goes to $0$) and so $P(z)$ converges absolute for $|z| = 1/2$ and so $P(z)$ converges for $|z| = 1/2$.

Comment: Or $\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}<\frac{1}{n^2}$, which converges by $p$-series.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left\lvert \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^nz^n}{(n+1)(n+2)}  \right\rvert \leq \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n \lvert z \rvert^n}{(n+1)(n+2)} \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$$

this leads to the fact, that partial sums form a Cauchy sequence, hence the convergence follows.